# Как запретить прием sms системе, если мое приложение уже приняло это сообщение?

Tags: android, sms

Написал по примеру с [хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149555/).

Получение *СМС*. Там автор написал, что высокий приоритет приложения позволяет перехватывать *СМС* у системы, и так и есть. Но проблема в том, что в систему *СМС* тоже приходит. Можно ли это запретить? То есть, если запущена моя программа, то она принимает *СМС* и дальше оно (сообщение) никуда не передаётся.

Мой код:

```
public class SMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
            }
            StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                bodyText.append(message.getMessageBody());
            }
            String body = bodyText.toString();
            Observer.getInstance().send(new SmsEvent(body));
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO не плолучитя. Разве что зарегистрировать приложение, как СМС приложение, вроде того, как это делает Hangouts. Но в этом случае **все** смс будут приходить именно в это приложение

Comment: С API19 никак. Для более ранних версий API ваш код будет работать корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Рискну предположить, что "перехватить" SMS у системы на Андроиде так же невозможно, как это невозможно на iOS **из соображений безопасности**.

Думаю, что в Андроиде (так же как в iOS) стек, отвечающий за приём и первичную обработку SMS отделён от основных Broadcast-API и защищён чтобы не допустить программ-шпионов, вроде вашей :)

Это сделано исключительно из соображений безопасности. Представьте, вы получаете код активации на WhatsApp или банковский одноразовый пароль. Ваш апп его перехватывает, а в стандартном инбоксе эти SMS не отображаются. Такая ОС будет изначально компрометировать действия пользователя.

Еще раз подчеркну, что мой ответ в части Андроида основан на *логически-обоснованных предположениях*. Про iOS я знаю точно.

Comment: Подобное поведение в андроид появилось сравнительно недавно - c API19 (Android 4.4 KitKat). До этого с СМС можно было делать что угодно, в том числе и перехватить без ведома пользователя :(

Comment: @pavlofff вы хотите сказать, что с новым API эти действия возможны? Но это же потенциальный рассадник для фишинговых программ.

Comment: @pavlofff все, я увидел объяснение в вашем комментарии ниже. Тогда это вполне логично и разумно.

Answer (score 0):

1) Создайте свой класс, например MyBroadCast, который будет наследоваться от класса `BroadcastReceiver`. Далее в манифесте пропишите для этого класса Intent-Filter `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"'`, и выставите для него большой приоритет, как то так:

```
        <receiver android:name=".MyBroadCast">   
           <intent-filter android:priority="999999">
             <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
```

2) Теперь в этом классе при приходе смс будет дергаться метод public void `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`. Вы можете сделать что нибудь с этой смс - забрать номер или текст, и далее вызвать метод `this.abortBroadcast()`. После него аппарат смс уже не получит.

Comment: Мне вот интересно, Вы вообще блин читаете тут вопросы? если не поленитесь, и поднимите глаза немного выше, то увидите мой код который я привел в вопросе. Я ИМЕННО так и делаю

Comment: Если у вас выставлен достаточно большой приоритет - то смс не должна приходить, это факт. Вы проверяли, выполнение кода до строки abort доходит?

Comment: я писал "Тоесть если запущена моя программа, то она принимает СМС" 
МОЯ ПРОГРАММА ПРИНИМАЕТ СМС И ПАРАЛЕЛЬНО С ЭТИМ СМС ПРИХОДИТ В INBOX

Comment: касательно вашего факта я нашел ответ "The abortBroadcast() does not DELETE messages from the inbox, it is just suppressing the status bar notification. To delete the sms from the inbox, refer to this link"

Comment: К сожалению видимо метод срабатывает не на всех версиях Andoid, так как у меня на 2.3.3 срабатывало без проблем, и телефон смс не получал

Comment: @Pavel начиная с API 19 работать с СМС может только одна программа, назначенная в системе клиентом по умолчанию. Из соображений, изложенных [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453153/177345)